# Putting List into Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, session, gridview

I have this Module in my project in which I have 2 gridviews. One is for the Main MenuModule and the other one is for it's subMenu. I created a List so that when a row on my Main Menu Module has been checked and it has a corresponding submenu, it will show on the SubMenu Gridview.

My problem was on how to put this list into session so that I when I navigate to another page and then get back to this page, the SubMenu Gridview will still be there.

Here's my code for the list.

```
protected void cbxSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    SubMenuGrid.DataSource = null;
    SubMenuGrid.DataBind();

    Business.SubMenuModules sub = new Business.SubMenuModules();

    List<oSubList> oList = new List<oSubList>();

    int counter = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow nRow in gvModuleList.Rows)
    {
        Int32 intModID = Convert.ToInt32(nRow.Cells[0].Text);
        CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)nRow.FindControl("cbxSelect");

        if (chkBx.Checked == true)
        {
            counter = counter + 1;

            var oModList = sub.GetAllMenuPerModuleID(intModID);

            if (oModList.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (var rec in oModList)
                {
                    oSubList olist = new oSubList
                    {
                        ID = rec.ID,
                        ModuleID = rec.ModuleID,
                        Submenu = rec.Submenu,
                        Description = rec.Description
                    };
                    oList.Add(olist);    
                }

                SubMenuGrid.DataSource = oList;
                SubMenuGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want it in Session? Don't you want to save the changes somewhere?

Comment: he goes with state management bcoz,values can be retained even after page expires..

Comment: i dont want to save it on my database yet, i just want to store it temporarily so that when I return to that page before submitting, I can see my submenu gridview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the list to session["list"].
on page load check the condition for user and assign the session value to menu..

```
protected void cbxSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        SubMenuGrid.DataSource = null;
        SubMenuGrid.DataBind();

        Business.SubMenuModules sub = new Business.SubMenuModules();

        List<oSubList> oList = new List<oSubList>();

        int counter = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow nRow in gvModuleList.Rows)
        {
            Int32 intModID = Convert.ToInt32(nRow.Cells[0].Text);
            CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)nRow.FindControl("cbxSelect");

            if (chkBx.Checked == true)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;

                var oModList = sub.GetAllMenuPerModuleID(intModID);

                if (oModList.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (var rec in oModList)
                    {
                        oSubList olist = new oSubList
                        {
                            ID = rec.ID,
                            ModuleID = rec.ModuleID,
                            Submenu = rec.Submenu,
                            Description = rec.Description
                        };
                        oList.Add(olist);    
                    }

                    Session["list"]=oList;

                    SubMenuGrid.DataSource = oList;
                    SubMenuGrid.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, will it be like this if I pass it on page load
 protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
           oList = Session["list"]
            Response.Redirect("~/Forms/RegReason.aspx");
        }

Comment: Yes it will ,but you have to restore the view by checking current logged in user or something..after checking just pass the session value to grid..

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick response! will it be like this If I pass it on Page load?
oList = Session["list"] what should be the index??

Comment: how can I pass the value to grid? is it like  oList = Session["list"] ?

Comment: No u just give response.redirect("~/Forms/RegReason.aspx"); from other page..then in regreason page load,give the below code..SubMenuGrid.DataSource = session["list"];                   SubMenuGrid.DataBind();

Comment: FOLLOW UP QUESTION that I forgot. MY submenugrid was already there when I return to that page,

How about the checkboxes I checked??! They're all gone when I return to it.

Comment: If answered for multiple questions in single thread,it wont be good for others when visiting this page later.Better post that as a seperate question..

Answer (score 0):

just assign your list to session simply and call it on submenu page.

on mainmenu page

```
Session["list"]=oList;
```

on submenu page

```
List<oSubList> subList = (List<oSubList>) Session["list"];
```